# jQuery image rotator plugin

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a suggestion on which jquery plugin will achieve what I want.

Basically I want to have 5 images on the page which change (fade in/out) automatically and when clicked on the image it goes to a page relative to the image.

For example: http://www.lorigrahamdesign.com/index.php?

In the page above there are images that fade/in/out automatically and there is a difference of some time so the transition looks good.

What is the best way to achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

or

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

While not fading, it does do sliding and is really cool and incredibly easy to use and get working:

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php

Comment: But i'm not able to click on the images? also, the fading in/out is important for me...

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this as well: [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html)

Since there are much configuration options it should be easy to add some appear-effects.

Comment: oups, GaVrA mentioned this one just a second ago!

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to something outside of jquery, you may want to look at this mootools plug-in.
[slideshow](http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/showcase). 
It's a little different from your example, but maybe you like it.